# Process URLs faster Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, cookies, web-scraping

I need to web-scrape HTML from various URLs that display real-time price data on auctions. I already have a pre-assembled list of URLs to check and currently, have a working script. The issue is that the processing time is not great (~1.5-2 seconds per URL).

I am using selenium with the chrome driver and running headless as an option to improve speed. The big issue (and why I'm using selenium) is that the site I'm using has strict login security (CSRF token as well as Captcha puzzles). Logging into the site is required in order to display live prices.

I have no desire to try and find away around the login. Instead, what I'm doing is loading a headed chrome window, manually logging in once, saving cookies. Initiating various amounts of headless chrome windows and loading cookies so I am already logged in and then going about my business web scraping. This is working, however, I would like to implement this somehow with urllib or a real headless browser instead of making chrome headless (I feel like that would be faster).

If there is a way for me to log in manually and somehow load cookies into a different headless browser, that would be ideal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for something like [Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library, if you looking for a normal scraping. Otherwise you can go for [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) framework. However from what I understand , Beautifulsoup will suffice your requirement.

Comment: thanks but i dont think it will. i need to login manually using a headed browser